# Python: Find duplicate x values in a 2D array and choose one duplicate x,y pair based on y value

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates

I have a 2D array of x,y pairs, where x=cmp number (distance) and y=twtt (depth).

Several of the x,y pairs are repeated and I would like to extract only one of the duplicates - the one where y is greatest.
However in some cases the x value is not a duplicate, but very similar and I would still like to extract the similar pair with greatest y.

To be a bit more clear: the images below shows the data, I would like to extract the bottom line only, which is not quite as easy as extracting y greater than a certain value.

Ideally, any ideas of an elegant way to extract the bottom line only (considering the non-duplicates) please let me know. Otherwise if someone could suggest how to select one of the duplicate pairs only that would be helpful.

I thought it might be possible to sort the array, so matching pairs are next to each other then remove the pair with lowest y?

Here is my code so far:

```
# Extract and read in data.
all_cmps=[]
all_twtts=[]
for i in os.listdir('/wgdisk/moon001/USERS/klg48/JCR298/reflector_tracking/outputs/line62/cmp1to5600_25to200ms/midpoints/cg1_ml320_ctg0.02_mtg0.01/lines/'):
    if i.endswith(".dat"): 
    contour_val=float(i.split("_")[1])
    if contour_val == -0.9:
      print "ok:",contour_val
      data=np.genfromtxt('/wgdisk/moon001/USERS/klg48/JCR298/reflector_tracking/outputs/line62/cmp1to5600_25to200ms/midpoints/cg1_ml320_ctg0.02_mtg0.01/lines/'+i+'')
      cmps=data[:,[0]]
      twtts=data[:,[1]]
      for j in range(len(twtts)):
        if twtts[j] > 0.05 and twtts[j] < 0.1:
          all_cmps=np.append(all_cmps,cmps[j])
          all_twtts=np.append(all_twtts,twtts[j])
    else:
      print "not chosen contour val, skipping:",contour_val
else:
    print "Unrecognized format"

print "CMP range", min(all_cmps), max(all_cmps), "      TWTT range", min(all_twtts), max(all_twtts)

# Use column stack to stack 1d arrays into a multi-dimensional array.
stack=np.column_stack((all_cmps,all_twtts))
```

[image: A plot of the data. I would effectively like to extract the bottom line shown here.]

Comment: Can there ever be more than two Y values?

Comment: Two of the same y values next to each other? No there shouldn't be. If there is, it would not be a problem to remove one of them. There will be repeated y values across the whole array however.